# How to save data and format of a pivot table?

Tags: pivot-table

How to save pivot table changes (and table format) after sychronization?

I tried to duplicate the pivote table and rename it so that I stay on this format whenever I update data (as the table is linked to other tables via Power Query on Excel). But I can't find my renamed table among the selection. And whenever I save and sychronize changes, the table goes back to its initial (incompleted) version and format.

Comment: It seems an off-topic question to me